# Sort an array based on antoher and add key if not exist

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Trying to sort `$object['data']` with the `$sort` array. The problem is, if a key doesn't exist in the object I would like to add it and set it to 0.

```
$sort = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4', 'label5'] /* Could be everything */
```

Actual object:

```
$object = [ array(
  "id"=>1,
  "name"=>"john",
  "data"=> ["label3"=>15, "label5"=>2]
), array(
  "id"=> 2,
  "name"=> "jane",
  "data"=> ["label1"=> 8, "label2"=>9, "label5"=>3]
)];
```

Desired object:

```
$object = [ array(
  "id"=>1,
  "name"=>"john",
  "data"=> ["label1"=>0, "label2"=>0, "label3"=>15, "label4"=>0, "label5"=>2]
), array(
  "id"=> 2,
  "name"=> "jane",
  "data"=> ["label1"=>8, "label2"=>9, "label3"=>0, "label4"=>0, "label5"=>3]
)];
```

I tried with `array_key_exists` in loops but actually with no luck.

Comment: It would be lot easier if you could try to implement this logic on raw array i.e. before applying `json_encode()` function, it would be lot easier. Incorporating this logic on JSON string would be expensive.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul i edited the code

Comment: I've given an answer below, hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `$object` is your original array, and `$sort` is the array with which you want to manipulate the original array, **the solution** would be like this:

```
function mergeArrays($array1, $array2){
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($array1 as $v){
        if(!array_key_exists($v, $array2)){
            $newArray[$v] = 0; 
        }else{
            $newArray[$v] = $array2[$v]; 
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}

foreach($object as $key => $array){
    $object[$key]['data'] = mergeArrays($sort, $array['data']);
}

// display $object array
var_dump($object);
```

---

Here's the [**live demo**](https://eval.in/658276).

Comment: @mchev Glad I could help. *Cheers! :-)*